# Fierz Identity problem in P&S

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices

I have a few questions about the Fierz identity. First of all in general form it has terms as $(\bar u_1\Gamma^Au_2)(\bar u_3\Gamma^Bu_4)$ which is a product of Dirac field bilinears. The question is what sort of a product it is? I guess that this is not an inner product between the two spinors, because $ \bar u_2 \cdot u_3=0$.
Next I'm trying to solve problem 3.6 in P&S, where I need to find coefficients C in the general Fierz identity below using completeness relation of $\Gamma^A$ $$(\bar u_1\Gamma^Au_2)(\bar u_3\Gamma^Bu_4)= \sum_{C,D} C^{AB}_{CD} (\bar u_1\Gamma^Cu_4)(\bar u_3\Gamma^Du_2) $$ 
Usually such problems are solved with multiplying both sides by a similar term, but I don't understand how to get rid of all the spinors in the expression. But even if I manage to get rid of the spinors by assuming all of the spinors being equal to identity, I still fail to understand how to proceed.

Comment: Inner products are usually taken to be non-degenerate. But they can be degenerate, as is the case here...

Comment: You might want to have a look at the book "Supergravity" by Freedman & Van Proeyen (freely available at http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~alberto/apuntes/freedman.pdf). They did a pretty good job at explaining it (chapter 3).

Comment: Direct products. [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fierz_identity) first.

Comment: I still struggling with this problem. I tried following your comments. Can anyone try answering the questions that I asked?